mark bundle as not supporting multiuse http/1.1 404 not found
When I am using this command to connect the websocket from local:
curl -i -N \
  -H "Connection: Upgrade" \
  -H "Upgrade: websocket" \
  -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" \
  -H "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" \
  http://localhost:6100/admin-api/websocket?access_token=1

the response shows error mark bundle as not supporting multiuse http/1.1 404 not found. I am sure the websocket endpoint exists and works fine for the internet users.
